# IBM Cloud Functions - Storing sensitive data (environment variables) with Docker based actions

Tags: docker, ibm-cloud-functions

I am looking for a recommendation how to do this.

From the docs:

https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/openwhisk?topic=cloud-functions-creating-docker-actions#creating-and-invoking-a-docker-action

> You can use actions to call images from public registries only, such
>   as an image that is publicly available on Docker Hub. Private
>   registries are not supported.

How to store database credentials, api keys etc... when the Docker image must be publicly available on Docker Hub?

Comment: Move them out to the environment? If they're baked into your containers it's harder to rotate them, anyway.

Comment: Can you be more specific? I have a web enabled action, written in php, that needs to talk to database and rabbitmq, send emails using sendgrid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [default parameters](https://github.com/apache/incubator-openwhisk/blob/master/docs/parameters.md#setting-default-parameters-on-an-action) to store credentials on actions. These parameters are stored securely by the platform and merged with request parameters during invocations.

Default parameters can be set by the CLI using the `-p` parameter when creating or updating actions.

```
ibmcloud wsk action create my_action -p name value ...
```